# How many directory servers are there in the Tor networks?

Tags: directory, consensus

I recently become interested in researching about the Tor network, and do want to do some research about it. I was heard that there are around 10 directory servers which are hard-coded into the Tor Browser Bundle. So could anyone please tell me what are the addresses of these directory servers and how can I get the consensus data from those server for research purpose.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 9 directory authorities which are hard-coded into the Tor software. Following please find addresses and some additional information about these directory authorites:
https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/flag:authority

Comment: Thank you Roya for the prompt answer!
I will be looking around your link. Furthermore, if you have any idea about how to GET consensus data from those authority servers, please show me cos I already read some papers which showed how to take the data, and published since 2009. However, those tools seem to be out of date and cannot be used.